# solution sought for a function on integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my work I came across that sequence

$1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1\ldots$ and so on forever

Now I cant find an expression $f(n)$ which gives me the sequence 
starting with $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$ and so on forever.

May it be a trigonometric function $f$ because of the periodicity of the
sequence?

Comment: What are the dashes in your sequence? Minus signs? Something to separate different elements of the sequence?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sin \dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{4}$. Use $2n+1$ if you start indexing with $0$.

Comment: $f_n=-1^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}$

Comment: Is the length of the cycle 4 or 22?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

$ f(n) = (-1)^{\lfloor{n\over2}\rfloor}$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor = x + $${\arctan (\cot (\Pi ⋅x ))}\over{\Pi} $$-$$1\over2 $